# JS - For an array of nested objects, each object having different keys, is it possible to copy each to a new object, copying only non-zero values?

Tags: object, filter, nested, mapping, javascript-objects

I have an array of many nested objects.

Each object has both properties with non-zero and with zero values.

Original object 1

```
{
    pigs: 0,
    water buffalo: 1
    
}
```

Original object 2

```
{
    horses: 1,
    cows: 0,
    magical: {
        unicorns: { European: 0 },
        centaurs: { Mongolian: 1 },
        dragons: {
            green: 2,
            black: 0
        }
    }
}
```

Desired new object 1

```
{
    water buffalo: 1
}
```

Desired new object 2

```
{
    horses: 1,
    magical: {
        centaurs: { Mongolian: 1 },
        dragons: {
            green: 2
        }        
    }
}
```

Attempt so far:  This works to find non-zero values,

```
for (let [i,x] of array.entries()) {

    for (let [j, y] of Object.entries(z)) {

        for (let [k, z] of Object.entries(y){

            if (z != 0) {
                console.log(z)

            // newObj[j] = {}
            // newObj[j][k] = z
            // console.log(newObj)

            }

        }
    }
}
```

...but when I try to turn them into a new object (commented-out section), it only retains the port of the object from the last iteration over the loop.

```
{

    magical: {
        centaurs: { Mongolian: 1 },
        dragons: {
            green: 2
        }        
    }
 }
```

missing is :  { horses: 1 }

IS there a general approach to (conditionally) filtering/mapping nested objects, where you don't know the properties beforehand?

Thank you!!!